# Diffeomorphisms from spheres in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function, diffeomorphism

I'm stuck  in the following exercise:

> Let $f:B_r (x_0) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a diffeomorphism from $B_r (x_0)$ onto $f(B_r (x_0))$. If $\|f'(x)^{-1}\|\leq M$ for all $x\in B_r (x_0)$ and $|f(x_0)|\leq r/M$, then $0\in f(B_r (x_0))$.

I've tried using the mean-value inequality to find a sequence converging to zero, but it doesn't seem to be any hypothesis on the bound $M$, so I'm not sure if that's the right way to prove it. Since the only point of the domain I know something about is the center $x_0$, I guess I should try to show the origin belongs to some neighborhood of $f(x_0)$, but I'm not sure how to do it. 
Could someone help me?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @Luan: For starters, can you do this if $n = 1$? If not, why not...? ;)

Comment: @FlybyNight I added some of my initial thoughts about the problem.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I tried it her for n =1, but I'm not sure how to proceed. The image is clearly open, but even with the hypothesis that $f(x_0)$ lies in the interval $[-r/M, r/M]$ I couldn't figure out why the image must contain $0$.

Comment: @DouglasFinamore: The mean value theorem gives $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq \frac{1}{M}|x - y|$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $B_{r}(x_{0})$, from which it follows that $f$ is monotone, and the image of $B_{r}(x_{0})$ contains $B_{r/M}(f(x_{0}))$.

Comment: Of course! It turns out I made a mistake when applying the mean value theorem, no wonder I couldn't get anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch**: The derivative hypothesis $\|f'(x)^{-1}\| = \|(f^{-1})'(f(x))\| \leq M$ gives $\|f'(x)\| \geq 1/M$ for all $x$ with $\|x - x_{0}\| < r$. By the inverse function theorem, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.

The mean value theorem shows that if $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary points of $B_{r}(x_{0})$, then $\|f(x) - f(y)\| \geq \frac{1}{M}\|x - y\|$. Particularly, if $0 < r_{0} < r$, then $f$ maps the sphere of radius $r_{0}$ about $x_{0}$ to the exterior of the ball of radius $r_{0}/M$ about $f(x_{0})$.

This suffices to imply the image $f(B_{r}(x_{0}))$ contains the ball $B_{r/M}(f(x_{0}))$, though you need topological machinery to prove this if $n > 1$. (On the assumption this is homework from topology or analysis, have you recently learned any such as relative homology or de Rham cohomology for detecting mapping degrees?)